# Using particles.js

Tags: html, css, particles.js

I'm using particles.js as my background, but the particles only span till the size of the window, and disappear on scrolling down.
In an attempt to counter this, I added `position: fixed;` to its css selector. Although, the particles spanned the page completely, all the hyperlinks on the webpage got deactivated. Why does it happen? Any workaround?

**Edit:** Github repo for particles.js https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script src="particles.js"></script>
<script src="site/js/app.js"></script>
```

**CSS Implementation:**

```
#particles-js{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('');
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

For JS file, please refer to the above repository. Its actually `app.js` and `particles.js` that do the main work in plugin.

Comment: Please provide additional information, including a link to the (presumably) GitHub project where you found this library (there are many forks) and a small repro of how you set it up (please don't post your entire code file, though).

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your code where you implement the JS? That way we can see where you potentially went wrong or come up with a suitable solution for your circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved as following:

CSS

```
#particles-js{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.body-particles{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!-- SOME CSSs HERE -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="assets/css/particles.css">

         <!-- SOME SCRIPTS HERE -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-particles">

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- MY STUFF HERE, STYLED WITH MY CSS -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- particles.js container -->
        <div id="particles-js"></div>

        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="assets/js/particles.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

To get hyperlinks to work (alongside particles.js touch events) I added class mouseEvents to elements I need to focus (for example hyperlinks, navbar, etc.)

CSS

```
.body-particles{
  pointer-events: none;
}


.mouseEvents{
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

Comment: Might not be the best of methods. The z-index spoils the CSS!

Comment: Have you found any better way to do so? @HritikGupta